# Calling a constructor on custom view model changes output type to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, viewmodel

I'm developing a WebAPI service and have been confronted with a curious problem. When calling a ViewModel with a constructor why is the return type changed to JSON from XML?

Code from controller;

```
// GET api/Product/5
public MyViewModel GetProduct(Int64 id)
{
    // without a constructor this returns an xml
    //return new MyViewModel() { Name = "123" };

    // this changes type to json
    Product product = new Product();
    return new MyViewModel(product) { Name = "123" };
}
```

View Model class;

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ARequest", Namespace = "http://myschema.com/schemas/myviewmodel.xsd")]
public class MyViewModel : Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel(Product product)
    {
        // this constructor causes the type to switch from
        // xml to json - why?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is some weird behavior of the serializer. Add a default empty constructor to your model along with the other constructor:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
}

public MyViewModel(Product product)
{
}
```

But personally I would use a view model. A real one. Not some hybrid to which you are passing your domain model. Just have a simple POCO as view model. And a mapping layer that will map from the domain model.